# Maven : Build all dependencies but run tests on specific modules

Tags: maven, maven-3

Below is my project strucuture:

```
Master
|
|--A
|--B
|--C
```

C depends on A,B and Master. I want to  first compile Master, A, B and then C but run tests which are present only in the C module.

I want a command that can be used in Jenkins as well.

I went through http://www.jayway.com/2013/06/09/working-efficiently-with-maven-modules/ but using

> mvn -pl :C -am clean install

builds and runs tests in all the modules : Master, A and B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to run different goals for sub modules with a single command.

Let's assume you have a following structure:

```
Parent
|
|---ModuleA
|---ModuleB (Depends on ModuleC)
|---ModuleC
```

Now if you run `mvn clean install -pl :ModuleB` -am from the **root pom** (Parent), you can see that it builds Parent, ModuleC and ModuleB.

Either reorganize your codebase differently or run something like this: `mvn clean install -pl :ModuleB -Dmaven.test.skip=true && mvn test -pl :ModuleB`

Comment: I can use two commands. How do I specify the same option in Jenkins ?

Comment: I assume you have a Maven Project in Jenkins? Probably the easiest way is to create a Freestyle Project and execute that command as a normal shell command. Or you can also add the first half of the command as a Build Pre Step.

Comment: The original question didn't ask anything about Jenkins; and if you are satisfied with the answer, don't forget to approve my it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can skip tests by specifying in the pom.xml of A and B.

See this: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html